# declare class in typescript with declare word

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript

What is the usage of ***declare*** class?whereas we can remove ***declare*** word???

```
 export declare class DialogContentBase {
        dialogTitleBar: DialogTitleBarComponent;
    }
```

As we can simply define the class like this:

```
 export class DialogContentBase {
        dialogTitleBar: DialogTitleBarComponent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare is used for defining interfaces for code that comes from outside your codebase: https://dzone.com/articles/quick-tip-%E2%80%93-typescript-declare

e.g.

If you include globally a library from somewhere outside your codebase and you want to use it (you put it in index.html for example) you can use `declare` to declare the typings for it.

You should not use it in your usecase.